# Porting from Access 2007 to 2010 fails on validating an XML using an XSD

Tags: xml, vba, ms-access, xsd

I'm validating XML against XSD.

This is the function that I used :

```vb
Public Function ValidaXML(ByVal strXMLPath As String, _
                          ByVal strXSDPath As String) As Boolean
    Dim objSchemas As MSXML2.XMLSchemaCache40
    Dim objXML As MSXML2.DOMDocument40
    Dim objXSD As MSXML2.DOMDocument40
    Dim strNamespace As String
    Dim objErr As MSXML2.IXMLDOMParseError

    ' load XSD as DOM to populate in Schema Cache
    Set objXSD = New MSXML2.DOMDocument40
    objXSD.async = False
    If Not objXSD.Load(strXSDPath) Then
       Err.Raise 1, "ValidaXML", "Load XSD failed: " & objXSD.parseError.reason
    Else
        ' get namespace name from XSD targetNamespace attribute
        strNamespace = objXSD.documentElement.getAttribute("targetNamespace")
    End If

    ' populate schema cache
    Set objSchemas = New MSXML2.XMLSchemaCache40
    objSchemas.Add strNamespace, objXSD

    ' load XML file (without validation - that comes later)
    Set objXML = New MSXML2.DOMDocument40
    objXML.async = False
    objXML.validateOnParse = False
    objXML.resolveExternals = False

    ' load XML, without any validation
    If Not objXML.Load(strXMLPath) Then
       Err.Raise 1, "ValidaXML", "Load XML failed: " & objXML.parseError.reason
    End If

    ' bind Schema Cache to DOM
    Set objXML.schemas = objSchemas

    ' does this XML measure up?
    Set objErr = objXML.Validate()

    ' any good?
    ValidaXML = (objErr.errorCode = 0)
    If objErr.errorCode <> 0 Then
       Err.Raise 1, "ValidaXML", objErr.reason
    End If
End Function
```

The instruction that I used is :

```vb
Private Sub valida_Click()
Call ValidaXML("C:\xq10\q19\recibos.xml", "C:\xq10\xml\pain.008.001.02.xsd")
End Sub
```

With Microsoft Access 2007 the function works OK. But when I use Access 2010, I get error in the first line with:

```vb
Set objXSD = New MSXML2.DOMDocument40
```

The error I receive is:

> Run-time error '429': ActiveX component can't create object

I really appreciate any help you can provide.

Comment: Please show the exact error and stacktrace. Otherwise it'll be impossible to just guess what's happening: [ask].

Comment: The exact error is “Run-time error '429': ActiveX component can't create object”? . I have Windows 7 - 64 bits and the reference Microsoft XML v 6.0 in VBA.

Comment: Yes, so then it is exactly like I said in my answer, you have not referenced MSXML 4.0. To make it clearer, I have updated my answer with more info.

Comment: PS: I have updated your question. Note that you can [edit your question](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/32539490/edit) yourself as often as you like until you find it perfect.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

While you didn't (yet) give the error, I am going to guess that this is a reference error, because you get it on the instantiation line.

This [MSDN post shows how to reference MSXML 4.0 for Office 2010 in VBA](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms763701%28v=vs.85%29.aspx). After you add the reference, your code should work as in Access 2007.

**Edit**: you say you received error 429, which shows indeed that the object could not be created. You use MSXML 4.0, which is not installed on every Windows system by default. You say you reference MSXML 6.0, in which case you should update your code to reflect this:

```
Set objXSD = New MSXML2.DOMDocument60
```

There may be other places in your code where you need to apply such changes. Hint: when it says "40", it means "4.0", when it says nothing, it means "3.0", when it says "60", it means "6.0". Avoid any other version than 3.0 and 6.0 if you want your code to run on any recent Windows system.

Here is an excellent answer on SO explaining [why and when you should choose what version of MSXML](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12848825/111575).

Comment: I changed the variables to MSXML 6

Comment: I changed the variables to MSXML 6. e.g.  Dim objSchemas As MSXML2.XMLSchemaCache60 instead of  Dim objSchemas As MSXML2.XMLSchemaCache40 ... .       And then it works fine. Thanks.